# Мод или ИИ для добычи блоков в маинкрафт на режиме Prison

Tags: java, искусственный-интеллект, minecraft

Есть режим в мини играх на сервере VineWorld, а точнее Prison. Банальная гриндилка, то есть добываешь ресурсы для того чтобы добывать потом более крутые ресурсы.

Вопрос в чем, как создать мод или же ИИ который сам будет добывать блоки например землю, гравий, песок в определенном чанке?

Ниже представляю вам Гифку которая коротко описывает как и что.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDwtA.jpg

То есть главная задача это не прерывно добывать блоки дабы счетчик добытых блоков автоматически пополнялся.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ простейший. Изучить теоретические основы ИИ и ознакомиться с  практическими примерами его использования.  Потом (впрочем, можно и параллельно) освоить один из языков программирования. В зависимости от выбора языка -  освоить инструментарий, который позволяет создавать приложения с задачами ИИ в экосистеме этого языка. Если вы уже выбрали java - можно и его, конечно, если им уже владеете достаточно свободно. Параллельно (а можно и потом) -  изучить какой-нибудь движок создания игр (какой -  советовать не буду, просто пока дойдете до этого пункта наверняка мода в геймдеве поменяется, поэтому будете определяться потом). Разобраться в тонкостях (и даже возможностях) взиамодействия написанных вами программ с теми, в работу которых вы пытаетесь вклинится.  Ну вот, а после этого уже легко можно приступать  к "*созданию мод или же ИИ который сам будет добывать блоки например землю, гравий, песок в определенном чанке*". При этом всем, конечно, придется отказаться от игры в игры - просто на них не останется времени.

Впрочем, рекомендую все таки начать с того, что сконцентрироваться на успешном окончании - судя по вопросу - седьмого класса, а описанными выше вещами заняться на летних каникулах.

Comment: Надеюсь вы повысили свое ЧСВ данным ответом. Спасибо.

Comment: @ Optimuc А я надеюсь, что вы поняли из моего ответа, что что-бы сделать то, что вы хотите, надо предварительно выучть очень и очень много. И "создание ИИ" - это не "добыча блоков  в определенном чанке".  А уж приоритеты того, на что тратить свое время, у каждого свои.

Comment: Вы правы, и в этом плане я не спорю, конечно мне далеко до вашего мышление в программировании.